# [OCMock]A question about the andDo function

Tags: ios, ocmock

## 1.code show as below：

```
[[OCMExpect([[self.mockDelegate ignoringNonObjectArgs] adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY statusChanged:statusStarted]) ignoringNonObjectArgs] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        ...
        ...
    }];
```

I broke the point and found that andDo is only executed works once(when `status==statusStarted`).The function is not triggered when `status==statusEnded`.
But when I copied the above code and found that the andDo function was triggered when `status==statusEnded`.
code show as below：

```
[[OCMExpect([[self.mockDelegate ignoringNonObjectArgs] adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY statusChanged:statusStarted]) ignoringNonObjectArgs] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        ...
        ...
    }];
[[OCMExpect([[self.mockDelegate ignoringNonObjectArgs] adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY statusChanged:statusStarted]) ignoringNonObjectArgs] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        ...
        ...
    }];
```

#### what's the reason？

## 2.an additional question

After experimenting I found that OCMVerifyAllWithDelay(self.adMockDelegate, 10) is not equivalent to：

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
 OCMVerifyAll(self.adMockDelegate);
    });
```

OCMVerifyAllWithDelay blocks the thread for 10 seconds,instead of extending the verification time of the mock by 10 seconds.why？

Comment: Could you try this with sticking to either the old or the new syntax, not mixing both?

Comment: About ignoringNonObjectArgs ,I've tried each individually, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I updated the description of the problem to add a newly discovered doubt.